# Angular momentum conservation during collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, collision

If I have a disk which is pure rolling and it strikes with a ladder, so can I conserve angular momentum about point O?
I think I can because normal reaction passes through O, so torque due to it will be zero. But using it, I am getting wrong answer.
[image]

I have written following equations:

$L_i = L_f$

$mv(H-r) + \frac{MR^2}{2}\frac{v}{R} = (\frac{MR^2}{2}+MR^2) \frac{v'}{R}$

Please help me figure out the concept.

Comment: Consider the limiting case of a high step, where the contact is at h=R and the wheel bounces back. Do you have the right physics in that limit?

Comment: I think, the disk will lift off the ground a little, as on disk, a force in upward direction will be applied due to step, so as to maintain its pure rolling.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that angular momentum is conserved about $O$ is correct, since the only impulse that could give rise to an impulsive moment is the contact impulsive force at $O$. (To be slightly pedantic, it's inaccurate to call this a normal impulsive force, since a tangential component will also be present due to the no-slip condition)

I can spot a error in your angular moment balance which appears to be the culprit. Hint: $R > H$. Other than that, the physics is all good. :)

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Is it correct to say that velocity which is tangent to Line Of Contact will be the only velocity after collision (thorough 2-D collision), as velocity along Line of Contact will be 0 after collision (perfectly inelastic) ?

Comment: That's right, the velocity of the centre of mass must be perpendicular to the line of contact, due to the no-slip condition, the disc must pivot about the point of contact after the collision. Being able to enforce the no-slip condition, however, relies on the assumption that contact is maintained between the disc and the step after the collision! (If $H$ is large enough, it is possible the disc might bounce back!)

Comment: But using this method, I am getting different answer.

Comment: Ok, then in what way is your answer and their answer different? Are there extra details to the problem that you haven't considered? e.g. the disc is just a wire, a so the moment of inertia is $J = MR^2$ instead of $J = \frac{1}{2}MR^2$. Is pure rolling/no slip a valid assumption? etc.

Comment: I mean, the answers I am getting from both methods discussed above are different, you can also check. But acc. to physics, there should be only one answer. So, which one is correct?

Comment: It would be great to see what answers they are providing, so I can talk about it!